# Swapping jpanels on actionlistener event

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I'm writing a gui program that basically removes and adds jpanels when certain buttons are clicked.  I'm trying to create a hierarchy of jpanels:
Here's the hierarchy

`Opener
  Mammal
    Tiger
      Tiger_caged //terminating button
      Tiger_riding //terminating button
  Reptile
    Frog
      Frog_eating //terminating button
      Frog_null //terminating button`

The initial jpanel is opener which is added to the JFrame on start up.
`Opener` will have mammal and reptile.
Each of those buttons, when clicked, will call `swap(currentJPanel)`, which then calls `removeall()`, `repaint()`, and `revalidate()` then adds the next JPanel under them with x buttons, each which calls `swap(currentJPanel)` method.  This will continue until until you reach the terminating JPanel with buttons that, when clicked, does x action, and then calls `reset()` which asks if the user wants to continue the game or get the result.  If continue game is selected, then `removeall()`, `repaint()`, `revalidate()` and add `opener` again.

I created a jPanel called `content` to place each of my JPanels in, added `opener` to `content`, and added `content` to the JFrame.  The buttons that are not in opener should not be added to the JFrame until a certain button is clicked.  Below is my current code.  When I run the gui, all of the buttons I have created are visible.  Only buttons Reptile and Mammal should be visible on startup.  Also, when one of the buttons are clicked, nothing is removed or added.  The only button that works currectly is the getResult button, which is the only one that doesn't call swap().  My initial thought is that I can't pass a jButton to a method but no error comes up when I call swap() so I'm not sure.  Any help and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```js
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class DreamInterpreter extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   private final LayoutManager layoutMain;

   private String result = "";
   private JLabel question = new JLabel("What was in your dream?");
   private String reset = "What was in your dream?";
   private JTextArea showResult;

//BUTTONS
   private JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
   private JButton getResult= new JButton("INTERPRET MY DREAM");
   private JButton continueGame = new JButton("Add more to my dream");

   private JButton animal = new JButton("Animal");
      private JButton mammal = new JButton("Mammal");
         private JButton tiger= new JButton("Tiger");
         private JButton tiger_caged= new JButton("The tiger is in a cage");
         private JButton tiger_riding= new JButton("The tiger is being ridden");
      private JButton reptile = new JButton("Reptile");
         private JButton frog= new JButton("Frog");
         private JButton frog_eating= new JButton("Eating");
         private JButton frog_null= new JButton("None of these");
   private JButton person = new JButton("Person");
   private JButton location = new JButton("Location");


//PANELS

   //DEFAULT PANEL
   JPanel standard;
   JPanel content;

   JPanel opener;
   JPanel jContinueGame;
   
   JPanel jAnimal, jPerson, jLocation;
      JPanel jMammal, jReptile;
         JPanel jTiger;
         JPanel jFrog;
   

   public DreamInterpreter(){

      super("Dream Interpreter");
      layoutMain = new BorderLayout(); // add components with add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER (NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST)
      setLayout(layoutMain);

      exit.addActionListener(this);
      getResult.addActionListener(this);
      continueGame.addActionListener(this);

      animal.addActionListener(this);
      person.addActionListener(this);
      location.addActionListener(this);

      mammal.addActionListener(this);
      reptile.addActionListener(this);

      frog.addActionListener(this);
      frog_eating.addActionListener(this);
      frog_null.addActionListener(this);

      tiger.addActionListener(this);
      tiger_caged.addActionListener(this);
      tiger_riding.addActionListener(this);

//FORMATTING LAYOUT
      showResult = new JTextArea(15,20);
//DEFAULT
      standard = new JPanel();
      standard.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,8));
//HEADER
      JPanel header = new JPanel();
      header.add(question);
//OPENER
      opener = standard;
      opener.add(animal);
      opener.add(location);
      opener.add(person);
//CONTENT
      content = new JPanel();
      content.add(opener);
//CONTINUE GAME

      jContinueGame = standard;
      jContinueGame.add(continueGame);
      jContinueGame.add(getResult);

//DECLARE OTHER JPANELS
      
      jAnimal = jPerson = jLocation = standard;
      jMammal = jReptile = standard;
      jFrog = jTiger = standard;
      
      add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      
//ADDING

   //jAnimal
         jAnimal.add(mammal);
         jAnimal.add(reptile);
            jMammal.add(tiger);
               jTiger.add(tiger_caged);
               jTiger.add(tiger_riding);
            jReptile.add(frog);
               jFrog.add(frog_eating);
               jFrog.add(frog_null);
   //jPerson
   //jLocation

   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

      if(event.getSource() == animal){
         swap(jAnimal);
         question.setText("What kind of animal was in your dream?");
      }
         if(event.getSource() == mammal){
            swap(jMammal);
            question.setText("What kind of mammal was in your dream?");
         }
            if(event.getSource() == tiger){
               swap(jTiger);
               question.setText("What was the tiger doing?");
            }
               if(event.getSource() == tiger_caged){
                  result += "";
                  reset();
               }
               if(event.getSource() == tiger_riding){
                  result+="";
                  reset();
               }
         if(event.getSource() == reptile){
            swap(jReptile);
            question.setText("What kind of reptile was in your dream?");
         }
            if(event.getSource()==frog){
               swap(jFrog);
            }
               if(event.getSource()==frog_eating){
                  result+="";
                  reset();
               }
               if(event.getSource()==frog_null){
                  result+="";
                  reset();
               }

         if(event.getSource() == continueGame){
            swap(opener);
            question.setText("What was in your dream?");
         }
         if(event.getSource() == getResult){
            content.removeAll();
            content.revalidate();
            content.repaint();
            content.add(showResult);
            showResult.setText(""+result);
         }

   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
      DreamInterpreter dreamInterpreter = new DreamInterpreter();
      dreamInterpreter.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      dreamInterpreter.setSize(450, 350);
      dreamInterpreter.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void reset(){
      content.removeAll();
      content.revalidate();
      content.repaint();
      question.setText("What would you like to do?");
      content.add(jContinueGame);
   }
   
   public void swap(JPanel panel){
      content.removeAll();
      content.revalidate();
      content.repaint();
      content.add(panel);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a cursory look, I suspect your problem might be here:

```
  //DECLARE OTHER JPANELS
  jAnimal = jPerson = jLocation = standard;
  jMammal = jReptile = standard;
  jFrog = jTiger = standard;
```

The effect here is not to create multiple JPanels(), but rather to have all variables refer to the same JPanel instance. Therefore, when you add buttons using different variables, you're actually adding them to the same panel.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense, I was trying to create a default JPanel so that I can set default values for things like the hgap and vgap and have all my other jpanels have those values.  How would you suggest I do that? @roberto attias

Comment: you could define a function instantiating the panel, and then call it multiple times:

JPanel creator() {
  JPanel p = new JPanel();
  //configure panel
  return p;
}

jAnimal = creator();
jMammal = creator();
...

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks so much @roberto attias